# JQuery conflicts with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to run some JQuery in my website using bootstrap that is carousel slide and lightbox for gallery album but both of them do not work...

I have tried to apply `noConlict()` many times but it still doesn't work. 
Here the scripts I have

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));

            var jq-$.noConflict();
            jq(document).ready(function(){
                jq('#mySlide1').carousel({
                    interval:3000
                });
                jq('#mySlide1').carousel('cycle');
                jq("[rel^='lightbox']").prettyPhoto();              
            });
</script>
```

Comment: *"it still doesn't work"* is **not** a problem description. What is the problem? What are the symptoms (error messages)?

Comment: why you pluggin in jquery three times?

Comment: `var jq-$.noConflict();` is invalid syntax. the `-`should be a `=`.

Comment: @vittore I count four jQueries :)

Comment: @Phil I just didnt belive my eyes

Comment: @MattTabor just 2 of them doesnt work at all

Comment: @MattTabor Where's number #5?

Comment: @MattTabor It'S 4, the 5th one isn'T loaded, as `window.jQuery` does already exist.

Comment: Actually, that's some nice "spot the jQuery instances" game going on here :D

Comment: @JohannesH. Could have snuck another one in the GA loader :)

Comment: all of you....i am still blind using jquery....i just copy and insert it into my website....my purpose is to play carousel and album photo in one page but they cannot work in the same page....now i separate it into 2 pages then they can work out that is carousel is one page and the photo album is in another page...

Comment: any can tell me how to insert my script here??....i tried to do it but it failed due to many characters....

Comment: here is the script i have changed
the first

<script src="js/prototype.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
   
   var jq-$.noConflict();
   jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq('#mySlide1').carousel({
     interval:3000
    });
    jq('#mySlide1').carousel('cycle');
    jq("[rel^='lightbox']").prettyPhoto();    
   });
  </script>

Comment: hey guys.....it's working now.....let me confirm the mistake..the mistake is about the order of jqueries and the sign jq-$ is changed to be jq=$...am i right??? and it is not about because there are many jqueries....am i right???...for all, thanks for helping me to figure out the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Replace all your current code with this:

```
<script src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
// and the Google analytics script
```

You just need one version of jQuery here. I'd suggest you to use CDN link from Google for your jQuery

Comment: Prototype should go first, then jQuery (then put into *noConflict* mode)

Comment: ...and bootstrap last. (Bootstrap doesn't use $ as well, does it?)

Comment: @JohannesH. Bootstrap's written nicely to use the `jQuery` symbol in the global scope. It doesn't need to go last, just after jQuery (and before any code that uses the plugins).

Comment: Felix, i have changed it as you suggested but it still doesn't work ...here the change i made 
<code>

Comment: @felix, it still doesn't work....i don't know how to insert the code here.....because too many characters

Answer (score 0):

you have like 4 instances of jquery on the page!! just use one instance!!

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That'S not the issue though, they shouldn't confilct. the last one is used, period.

Comment: @JohannesH. I'd say the last one is blowing away all the Bootstrap event handlers and plugins (as it comes **after** the `bootstrap.min.js`) so it most probably **is** the problem

Comment: agreed, bootstrap should be called last, but there still should not be 5 instances of jQuery on the page :P